# Set font color for select option placeholder

Tags: html, css

Looking for a way to set the font color of a dropdown list placeholder. The following worked when the select id was required:

```
select:required:invalid {
    color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

However, I do not want these dropdown lists to be required for input. Once I remove the required tag, the placeholder font changes back to black.

The following is my dropdown list:

```
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
    <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
    <option>Football</option>
    <option>Basketball</option>
    <option>Baseball</option>
    <option>Softball</option>
    <option>Soccer</option>
    <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you show what you're doing in a snippet?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To directly address the `option` font color, we can set the color on the `select` element to the light grey, then set all the `option` font colors except the first to black.

This way, the first `option` inherits the light grey, and shows as such while the `select` is both open and closed.

```css
select {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
option:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
  <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
  <option>Football</option>
  <option>Basketball</option>
  <option>Baseball</option>
  <option>Softball</option>
  <option>Soccer</option>
  <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Since the light grey font color is achieved by setting it on the `select` element, then `:not` overruling it when setting the `option` color to black, when a selection is made, the text will also show as grey.

If that is undesirable, we could change the color depending on whether the `select` has `:focus`, either showing the grey or black (depending on taste) when the element is or is not in use:

```css
/* with the :focus here, we would show grey when not using the element */
select {
  color: black;
}
/* with the :focus here, we show grey when using the element */
select:focus {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
option:first-of-type {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
  <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
  <option>Football</option>
  <option>Basketball</option>
  <option>Baseball</option>
  <option>Softball</option>
  <option>Soccer</option>
  <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

**Further to those possibilities:**

Although methods (including the following) can be employed to hide the initial/default non-value *(i.e. "Choose Primary Sport...")* when the `select` is open, **that might not be desirable**.

**NOTE:** Once an `option` has been selected, it is not possible to return to the default non-value initial state in the case of a change of mind.

If however this usability/accessibility issue is not a concern, here's a simple modification with the non-value default hidden when the select` is open:

```css
select {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
option:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: black;
}
/* the modification */
option:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
  <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
  <option>Football</option>
  <option>Basketball</option>
  <option>Baseball</option>
  <option>Softball</option>
  <option>Soccer</option>
  <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me; the options always inherit the select's color even if I put an !important on the options

Comment: @sammiepls - using what version of what browser on what platform do you see which of the above snippets fail to function as described?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, on Chrome 78.0

Answer (score 28):

Look at this way...

```css
select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Primary Sport...</option>
    <option>Football</option>
    <option>Basketball</option>
    <option>Baseball</option>
    <option>Softball</option>
    <option>Soccer</option>
    <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi. You may not have noticed that the question states "I do not want these dropdown lists to be required"; you may want to edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for this for a long time, and figured there isn't really a proper way to do this with only CSS (and not requiring a field) at the moment. So I did it with a bit of jQuery like so:

```
if (jQuery('select').length) {
    jQuery('select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "" || $(this).val() === null) {
            $(this).addClass('placeholder');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    });

    jQuery('select').on('change', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() === "" || $(this).val() === null) {
            $(this).addClass('placeholder');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my (S)CSS I did:

```
select {
    color: #000;
}

select.placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the current CSS that you have into this:

```
select, select[size="0"], select[size="1"] {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
```

this will make the same result with:

```
select:required:invalid {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

Without using required.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with pure javascript (to handle the `options` color property after the first click).
here is a  [working example](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=7333a033-6a7c-4880-b577-ff9c56356f15)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #myselect{
    color:gray;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="myselect">
      <option disabled selected>Choose Item
      </option>
      <option>Item 1
      </option>
      <option>Item 2
      </option>
      <option>Item 3
      </option>
    </select>
    <script>
      // add event listener to change color in the first click  
      document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("click",setColor)
      function setColor()
      {
        var combo = document.getElementById("myselect");
        combo.style.color = 'red';
        // remove Event Listener after the color is changed at the first click
        combo.removeEventListener("click", setColor);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest converting your answer's code into a functional snippet to allow readers to quickly see it in operation, with the bonus of separating the languages for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```css
select {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
option:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
  <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
  <option>Football</option>
  <option>Basketball</option>
  <option>Baseball</option>
  <option>Softball</option>
  <option>Soccer</option>
  <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using react, and I solved this with the condition

```
<select 
     style={{ color: data.state.length > 0 ? '#482668' : '#dad3e0' }}
>
    <option></option>
</select>

CSS
option {
   color: #482668
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
select {
    color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

```html
<select id="searchresults4" name="primarysport">
    <option value="">Choose Primary Sport...</option>
    <option>Football</option>
    <option>Basketball</option>
    <option>Baseball</option>
    <option>Softball</option>
    <option>Soccer</option>
    <option>Golf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.