# Change font color for select option placeholder without required

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of a select place holder. This can be done if the element is set to `required` and this CSS is used:

```
select:required:invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

Edit: here is an example of the select:

```
<select required>
    <option value="Placeholder" selected disabled hidden>Placeholder</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

However I can't find a working solution to this if it's not set to `required`.

This guy has the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579288/set-font-color-for-select-option-placeholder) as me in 2017 but none of the answers worked in Safari or Mobile Safari, hence why this is not a duplicate.

Is this possible without using JavaScript?

Comment: `option { color: red; }`?

Comment: @code does not work in safari.

Comment: What specifically do you want red?

Comment: The select box text itself. I want that to be red with the selected disabled placeholder is shown and black when any option besides that is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this??

```css
.myselect {
    color:red;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border-color:red;
    
    }
 
.black {    
    color:black;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border-color:black;
}
```

```html
<select class="myselect" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className"
    class="myselect">
    <option class="black" value="Placeholder" selected disabled hidden>Placeholder</option>
    <option class="black" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="black" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, not like that. When unfocus the select box it is red. That's not at all a solution and wouldn't look good with other form elements.

Comment: ok so select box will be red including the borders? I edited it If thats what you are looking at. Let me know

Comment: The place holder is red, and if you change it from 1 or 2 it is still red. The place holder should be red and the 1 or 2 should be black.

Comment: I update the code see if thats what you are trying to attain. Let me know.

Comment: I mean, I asked for a non JS solution but this works well. So I guess this is it.

Comment: @tony I know, I really cant think of the best approach. I will prob think more deeper and dig on my old brain to find this in my head for you :P

Comment: Let me know if you have any more ideas. I fear this might be the only solution. If you can't think of anything and I get no more answers, I'll accept this as the solution.

Comment: @tony someone might have more idea give it a day, But I will be glad if you accept it and move forward in life. :) cheers

Comment: Post here in a few days to remind me to accept it if nothing comes up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244276/discussion-between-crystal-and-tony).

Comment: This may "solve" the problem but is hardly a solid solution, and uses JavaScript. Not sure what y'all believe onChange is... I'm happy Crystal solved your immediate problem, but I doubt anyone else will gain anything meaningful from this answer. It is simply a one-time-only hack.
After reading this, I revised my answer below to satisfy your requirement more accurately.

Answer (score -1):

You say "without using JavaScript" but then accept an answer that uses JavaScript. If you simply want html5 to catch required and apply invalid, that happens automatically.

Your problem in this specific case is putting "Placeholder" in the value attribute of the first option. This causes the select to be valid. "Placeholder" is a valid value.

An empty value however is NOT valid, so just remove the "Placeholder" from the value attribute.

```
<select required>
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Placeholder</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

and your CSS would simply be:

```
select:required:invalid {
    color: red;
    border-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e78fgkb0/1/

Even with this solution, your UX is not ideal as the form loads showing "errors" to your user. The more acceptable UX is to show errors after the user has made a mistake in entering data. This usually requires some JavaScript to present a better UX, which is kinda why we use it to overcome the limitations of pure HTML and CSS.